# Why in [object,Object ] , there is one small o in first object an big O in secound Object

Tags: javascript

When creating a object in JavaScript if I want to get o/p of that object then it's showing [object,Object]. Let's say

```js
var a = {
  fname: "Avijit",
  lname: "Paul"
}

document.write(a);
```

o/p : [object,Object] // Why here one small object and another big Object?

Answer (score 0):

The first one is a reference to the object itself and the second one is the type that it is.

To get the data out of the object, you must access its properties:

```js
var a = {
  fname: "Avijit",
  lname: "Paul"
}

console.log(a.fname);
console.log(a.lname);
```

Also, `document.write()` while legal is for very limited use cases (usually when creating a new document dynamically) and can actually overwrite the current document if not used correctly. For outputting data for test purposes, use `console.log()` with the Console window of the developer tools (F12) open.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to access the value of the object. for that you will have to access it's property like,

```
document.write(a.fname);
```

Answer (score 0):

document.write() method writes string content to the document.

When you pass an object to it, in your case `a` like below:

```
var a = {
  fname: "Avijit",
  lname: "Paul"
}
```

Javascript tries its best to convert the object to a string.
In order to do that a method called toString() is called. This is defined in the `Object`. To be precise in `Object.prototype`.
Since the object you are passing is an object, it prints [object Object].

Note that in Javascript, there are many types of objects. A function is an object, arrays are objects. So to distinguish one object from the other they are shown as [object Function], [object Array] etc.

See some code below:

```js
var obj = {};
var arr = [1,2,3];
var func = function () {
  //console.log('A Func');
}
//func();
var objObj = Object.prototype.toString.call(obj);
console.log(objObj);//prints [object Object]
var arrObj = Object.prototype.toString.call(arr);
console.log(arrObj);//prints [object Array]
var funcObj = Object.prototype.toString.call(func);
console.log(funcObj);//prints [object Function]
```